# Is there way, to use bash variable stored in json?

Tags: json, bash, jq

I've got two simple files, bash script and json file:

```json
{
  "age": "22",
  "message": "You are ${age} years old"
}
```

```sh
age=$(jq -r .age file.json)
message=$(jq -r .message file.json)
echo ${message}
```

When echoing message, as output I've got

```
You are ${age} years old
```

not

```
You are 22 years old
```

Is there some way in this scenario, to replace `${age}` with variable (for bash to know, that there's variable in there, not just plain string)?
I could probably use `sed`, to manually replace it, but that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: how are you exactly "echoing", as `echo You are ${age} years old` works as intended

Comment: Can you use zsh instead?

Comment: I'm echoing `${message}`, and on zsh, I've got the same result.

Comment: Because that's not how you do what you want...

Comment: Yeah.. What I'm doing is probably the same as `message='You are ${age} years old'` (with single quotes). So it's plain string for bash/zsh/etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a single call to `jq` :

```
jq -r '.age as $age|.message|sub("\\${age}";$age)' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `envsubst` to replace the string `${stuff}` for exported variables.

```
age="$age" envsubst <<<"${message}"
```